# VueJS,v-model, добавление в массив по условию

Tags: vue.js, typescript, vuex

#### VueJS: v2.5.15

#### TypeScript: 2.8.3

#### Vuex: 3.0.1

---

Есть сущность:

```
export class Entity{
    b1 = false
    b2 = false
    b3 = false
}
```

И есть таблица в которой каждая строка представляет содержимое `Entity`.
В каждой строке таблицы есть по три `checkbox`.

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="entity.b1">
<input type="checkbox" v-model="entity.b2">
<input type="checkbox" v-model="entity.b3">
```

И еще есть массив для элементов `Entity` у которых хотя бы одно свойство равно `true`. Массив находится в `Vuex`

Если бы мне нужно было просто добавить элемент при выборе чекбокса  то сработал бы такой варинт:

```
<input type="checkbox" :value="entity" v-model="entityArray">
```

Но мне нужно что бы элемент попадал в этот массив по условию.

---

Я пробовал текущий массив копировать и добавлять в него новый элемент.
Добавление работает, но при удалении я получаю ошибку

```
[vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.
```

Все изменения массива приводились через метод `dispatch()`.
Прошу подсказать как решить данную проблему, если что то не понятно из вопроса могу расписать более подробно.

### UPDATE

Заметил что элементы корректно добавляются и удаляются из массива, но ошибка в консоли появляется только при удалении первого элемента если удалить 2-й  ошибки уже не будет.

Comment: vuex изменяет состояние **только** через мутации, то что вы через dispatch в экшен это завернули - никакого эффекта давать и не должно

Comment: @etki в action я вызываю мутацию так что не в этом дело и добавление элемента работает, а удаление нет